# Cannot install ZXing.Net.Mobile version 2.4.1

Tags: xamarin.android

I have installed Xamarin.Android bindings for Android Support Library version 28.0.0.1，But I still cannot install ZXing.Net.Mobile version 2.4.1 and get the following error.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 directly to project App1 to resolve this issue. 
>    App1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 28.0.0.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 28.0.0.1) 
>    App1 -> ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.4.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.1).  App1    C:\Users\Leon Lu\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.csproj 1

Comment: Why not just install the latest stable version of Zxing?